# Can access attr_accessor with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I declared attr_accessor :password in the top of my model

then, I try to do

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 6 }, :if => (password.present? or hashed_password.blank?)
```

But it throw exception and says that ruby don't know password field

why?

EDIT:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :email, :presence => true
  validates :password, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 6 }, :if => (password.present? or hashed_password.blank?)

  before_save :encrypt_password



    def encrypt_password
      if password.present?
        self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.hashed_password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: is it `accessible` as well? Show your model plz

Comment: sure: attr_accessible :name, :email, :password

Comment: Using `attr_accessor` on an ActiveRecord model does not create an attribute on it. Do you have a `password` column in your database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing to do with `attr_accessible` - the problem here is that you're calling `password` in the class context of the `validates` class method, and so it's not defined there.

You need to provide a lambda which Rails will pass the instance being validated to:

```
:if => lambda { |u| u.password.present? or u.hashed_password.blank? }
```