# Rails 3 - how to implement changing case of descriptions based on a check_box_tag (not part of model) in before_save callback in external class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, callback, activemodel

I have an rails 3 application where there are multiple registrations (diagnosis, patient, laboratory test, service, client, user, supplier). Initially these will be populated by seeding the database. The requirement is for the description codes to be mixed case (capitalised first word) when either 
1. specified by the application (some configuration setting - yet to be determined)
2. specified by data entry user

At present I have a model, view & controller for Diagnosis which contains two fields:
1. code (always to be capitalised)
2. description (First word capitalised based on check_box_tag value)

Presently I am using a before_save callback in the model to implement the conversion, but I cannot get it to only work when the check_box_tag is not selected i.e. its ignoring the check_box_tag.

I have tried changing the check_box_tag to a check_box adding an attr_assessor to the model (but not the sqlite3 db as it is not required to be stored).

This didn't work either.

How do I accomplish this? How do I override the option to use a checkbox from an internal application configuration file which results in either the checkbox being 'unavailable' or not visible if the application configuration specifies not user selectable?

Model (diagnosis.rb)

```
require 'DescriptionHelper'

class Diagnosis < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, description

  string_correct_case = DescriptionHelper.new([:code, :description])

  validates :code, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 4, :maximum => 4 }
  validates :description, :presence => true

  before_save string_correct_case

end
```

Callback in DescriptionHelper.rb

```
class DescriptionHelper
  def initialize(attribute)
    @attrs_to_manage = attribute
  end

  def before_save(record)
    @attrs_to_manage.each do |attribute|
      record.send("#{attribute}=", capitaliseWords(record.send("#{attribute}")))
    end
  end

  private
    def capitaliseWords(value)
      value = value.mb_chars.downcase.to_s.gsub(/\b\w/) { |first| first.upcase }
    end
  end
```

Controller (diagnoses_controller.rb)

```
class DiagnosesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @diagnosis = Diagnosis.new
  end

  def create
    @diagnosis = Diagnosis.new(params[:diagnosis])

    if @diagnosis.save
      flash[:notice] = "Diagnosis created with params [#{@diagnosis.attributes.inspect}" #for debugging, once fixed will be just 'Diagnosis created.'
      redirect_to @diagnosis
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Diagnosis not created."
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  .. other controller actions - edit, show, destroy

end
```

View (_form.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for(@daignosis) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %>
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= check_box_tag("diagnosis_desc_dont_convert", 1, false) %><%= f.label "Leave as entered" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When this runs currently the check_box_tag is ignored.

When adding in the model an attar_assessor :description_correctcase and changing the view to use f.check_box 'description_correctcase' this is still ignored.

How does one get this to work?

Thanks in advance from a rails aspiring developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution to the problem, after reading and re-reading various SO solutions to component parts of my question. I'm not sure its correct in terms of rails, but it works.

If you can offer me a better solution I would certainly learn from this.

Here is my solution.

Model (diagnosis.rb)

```
require 'DescriptionHelper'

class Diagnosis < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :do_not_correctcase
  attr_accessible :code, :description, :do_not_correctcase

  before_save DescriptionHelper.new([:code, :description]), :if => 
                         lambda { |d| d.do_not_correctcase.to_s == '0' }

  validates :code, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 4, :maximum => 4 }
  validates :description, :presence => true

end
```

This I referenced from the following SO solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6388691/1108010

Controller (diagnoses_controller.rb)

```
class DiagnosesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @diagnosis = Diagnosis.new
  end

  def create
    @diagnosis = Diagnosis.new(params[:diagnosis])
    @diagnosis.do_not_correctcase = params[:diagnosis][:do_not_correctcase]

    logger.debug "New diagnoses: #{@diagnosis.attributes.inspect}"
    logger.debug "Diagnosis should be valid: #{@diagnosis.valid?}"
    logger.debug "code has value #{params[:code]}"


    if @diagnosis.save
      flash[:notice] = "Diagnosis created with params [#{@diagnosis.attributes.inspect}" #for debugging
      redirect_to @diagnosis
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Diagnosis not created."
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  .. other controller actions - edit, show, destroy

end
```

I also changed the view to replace the check_box_tag with a check_box.

View (_form.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for(@daignosis) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %>
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box 'do_not_correctcase' %><%= f.label "Leave as entered" %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So despite getting this to work I'm not clear on are the following:

1. When inspecting the attributes with `"#{@diagnosis.attributes.inspect}"`.
   I assume that the reason the attr_accessor variable is not included in the New diagnosis output is that it is not part of the database table and therefore Active Reocrd does not instanciate it as part of the new record with @diagnosis.new
   Could someone be kind enough to confirm that.
2. Why does the log have no value for `logger.debug "code has value #{params[:code]}"`? What causes the `params[:code]` to be null in the logger output?

Logfile contained the following entry:

```
Started POST "/diagnoses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-05 09:36:38 +0000
  Processing by DiagnosesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RW/mzkhavGeaIW0hVLn0ortTnbCDlrX+FfzH4neLLsA=", "diagnosis"=>{"code"=>"tt02", "description"=>"description for tt02", "do_not_correctcase"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Diagnosis"}
New diagnosis: {"code"=>"tt02", "created_at"=>nil, "description"=>"description for tt02", "updated_at"=>nil}
Diagnosis should be valid: true
code has value
```

I would dearly like to know what is the correct way to do all this, as I feel this is not very DRY or clean.